# Unique Properties of Matrix

Tags: matrices, statistics

I am hoping you guys can point me in the right direction for what I should go read more on.

**Goal:** I have a sample data set of 3D matrices.  I want to determine if a new data point (3D matrix) is within the bounds of the original data set.

Is there some sort of unique property or some way to characterize these matrices?

I thought maybe I could approximate a characterization with the first 4 moments of the distribution, but I am wondering if there is something smarter and more exact out there that I just dont know about.

Comment: How would you go about solving this problem if you had real numbers or say 4-vectors instead of matrices? Do you know something special about the matrices, eg they’re all orthogonal or symmetric or normal or simultaneously diagonalisable or positive determinant?

Comment: If instead of a 3D matrix I had a vector for each data point, I would use "leverages", which are the diagonals of the projection matrix.

Each layer in the 3rd dimension of the 3D matrix should be diagonalisable. 

I also thought about "flattening" the 3D matrix into a vector to obtain leverages, but this results in a vector length of 200,000.  Seemed like I was getting off track at that point.

Comment: I think leverages would be a good idea. It certainly is a good start to forget that you have matrices and just treat them as vectors of data. I’m afraid I don’t really know too much about whether there’s a more computationally tractable way to get similar results. I guess it might take random subsets and calculate leverages in those and then average out those leverages over lots of subsets. I guess that would trade off time and accuracy for memory.

Comment: Cf [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40934748/how-to-accelerate-the-computation-of-leverage-diagonals-of-hat-matrix-in-least)

Comment: Hmmm, ok I will have to think about that.  Currently I have more data than can fit into my RAM.  I think it is possible to do LU decomposition in chunks, not sure I will have to read more.   

Your idea of sampling is interesting.  I hadn't considered that.  I will let that digest for bit.  Thanks. :-)

Answer (score -1):

I am not a mathematician but have studied similar sounding things in grad school economics and stats classes.

It is not clear to me what a data point in terms of a 3D matrix is.  Could you clarify or given an example?